# Inserting radio Button value into Access Database

Tags: c#, ms-access

I have this Code that is working except when I try to add Gender which is a Radio Button. I'm not sure how to do it.

```
            connection.Open();

            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
            command.Connection = connection;
            command.CommandText = "insert into Login1 (Username, bassword, WhereDoYouLive, MobileNumber,PlaceOfBirth ,IdNumber, Gender) values ('" + txtFullName.Text + "','" + txtPassword.Text + "','" + txtLive.Text + "','" + double.Parse(txtMobile.Text) + "','" + txtPob.Text + "','" + double.Parse(txtId.Text) + "')"; 

            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("Data saved");


            connection.Close();
```

Comment: Not clear here what is double, what is Parse and why you trying to extract radio button value from text property. You should read `Value` from radio button frame control, it will be number, not text. If you need text, read caption of related control.

Comment: I left the values section of the Gender column empty. I have two radio buttons but I'm not sure what the code is to insert values from a radio button. Or even a datetimePicker

Answer (score 0):

*Edited due to my blindness.

In C# you can check for a radio button checked property to see if its checked, and knowing that the radio buttons is a 2 choice exclusive, male or female, then you only need to check one.

```
 if (radiobuttonMale.Checked == true)
    stringforGender = radiobuttonMale.Text;
 else
    stringforGender = radiobuttonFemale.Text;
```

Comment: It's _C#_, not VBA.

Comment: @Lybren I'm talking about c# Would appreciate it if you can still help.